# Lapply a function over list of data tables, that requires reference to previous row

Tags: r, data.table, apply

I would like to apply an function over all rows of a data table, for all data tables in a list, however the function must refer to a previous row in the calculation (apart from row 1, which is independent)

I can do it when not needing to refer to the previous row;

```
require(data.table)

# dummy list data
l <- list(data.table(col1=c(2,3,4,2,1), col2=c(1,2,3,4,3), col3=c(5,4,3,4,5), col4=c(1,1,1,1,2)), data.table(col1=c(3,4,3,2,3), col2=c(1,3,4,2,2), col3=c(5,4,3,2,3), col4=c(5,5,5,5,5)))

# apply the function to the data table by row, and apply this function to all tables in the list
lapply(l, function(b) b[ , value := mapply(function(w,x,y,z) w + x + y * z, col1, col2, col3, col4)])
```

but how do i make `value` take into account `value` from the previous row?

```
# this wont work b'cos value hasn't been created yet
lapply(l, function(b) b[ , value := mapply(function(w,x,y,z) w + x + y * z, col1, col2, col3, col4)])

 Error in mapply(function(w, x, y, z, v) (w + x + y * z)/shift(v, 1), col1,  : 
  object 'value' not found 

# so make 'value' for row 1 only and try again
lapply(l, function(b) b[ , value := 0])
lapply(l, function(b) b[1 , value := col1 + col2 + col3 - col4])

# using shift inside mapply
lapply(l, function(b) b[ , value := mapply(function(w,x,y,z,v) (w + x + y * z) / shift(v,1), col1, col2, col3, col4, value)])
```

turns the `value` column all into NAs

Comment: since you are using datatable, if all the data.tables in the list have same number of columns, of which in this case it seems so, just make all of it be one data.table with a grouping ID

Comment: And also what is your expected output?

Comment: see the answer below, thanks for commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated to reflect other comments**

for this case couldn't you just avoid apply functions altogether and do something like:

```
names(l) <- c("list1","list2")
l <- rbindlist(l,idcol=TRUE)
l[,value := col1 + col2 + col3 * col4,by=.id]
l[,value2 := value / shift(value, fill = 1),by=.id]
```

which returns

```
      .id col1 col2 col3 col4 value     value2
 1: list1    2    1    5    1     8  8.0000000
 2: list1    3    2    4    1     9  1.1250000
 3: list1    4    3    3    1    10  1.1111111
 4: list1    2    4    4    1    10  1.0000000
 5: list1    1    3    5    2    14  1.4000000
 6: list2    3    1    5    5    29 29.0000000
 7: list2    4    3    4    5    27  0.9310345
 8: list2    3    4    3    5    22  0.8148148
 9: list2    2    2    2    5    14  0.6363636
10: list2    3    2    3    5    20  1.4285714
```

the important part here is the `fill` argument of the `shift()` function, [described here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.2/topics/shift)

Comment: sorry for being unclear but yes, you have answered my qu. That was just a toy function so doesn't make much sense but that is the principle i wanted answered, ta